# How to calculate the rowMeans with some single rows in data?

Tags: r

I tried to group a set of elements and to calculate the row means

If my list has more than one element, it works fine:

```
tapply(colnames(myMA), c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4), list)    
myMAmean <- sapply(myList, function(x) rowMeans(myMA[,x]))
```

However, in my data some of the rows are unique:

```
myList <- tapply(colnames(myMA), c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5), list)
myMAmean <- sapply(myList, function(x) rowMeans(myMA[,x]))
```

Notice the 4 & 5 it makes them as unique so if I run this it says

```
"Error in rowMeans(myMA[, x]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions"
```

I don't want to run a loop. Is there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can prevent the loss of the dimension attribute when using "[" with drop=FALSE:

```
tapply(colnames(myMA), c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4), list)
myMAmean <- sapply(myList, function(x) rowMeans(myMA[,x, drop=FALSE]))
```